# Controlling a website with phone/tablet

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs, backbone.js

I'm making a website which will when opened on the phone have two functions. To be used as regular website or as a remote for the same website opened on the PC.

Let me try to explain a bit better:

For example YouTube TV does exactly what i want to do. I want to be able to pair my Website and Phone(Website opened on the phone) so i can use my phone to control the website functions. For example executing JavaScript command with parameters sent from the Phone (Playing a video on PC that i selected on Phone)

I've been looking into this and so far using my limited skills of PHP/JS/MySQL i ended up making ajax that checks if theres queued command in DB to be executed ever so often (interval of 2 sec). But i dont really think thats the best option to go with even if ... It'll work somehow.

So please if you could give me some example where this is done right, some tutorials links or tools i can use it would be great.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

With your skill set, I don't think there is a real good way of doing this. However, it is "accordingly easy to do" with nodejs if you are familiar with.

If you are not, don't worry. Just try amazing "[meteor](https://www.meteor.com/try)". If you have knowledge on javascript and html, you will learn it in a very short amount of time.

I am suggesting you to learn meteor because they provided a protocol called [ddp](https://www.meteor.com/ddp) to get your request done in an easy way.

If you are interested in more detailed technical details, check [this link](https://meteorhacks.com/introduction-to-ddp.html).